# CONDITIONAL IF ELSE LEFT_JOIN DATASET in R (Try to Replicate Excel IF ELSE - INDEX MATCH PROBLEM)

Tags: r, excel

Hi I am new with R and Good with Excel.

Problem:
I have two(2) datasets:
a. Masterlist which contain **ID** and **NEW ID** I want to refer to other dataset.
b. Transaction dataset which contain a column of mix ID and old ID name **OFFICER ID**.

Desired Output to achieved:
I want to create a **new column name MERGE ID** in Transaction dataset to **only refer to one ID**.

Approach:
In ExceL (Please - Igbore and Read the Translated Formula) - for ref purpose:

> =IF(ISNA(INDEX(**ID**,MATCH(OFFICER ID,**ID**,0))),INDEX(**ID**,MATCH(OFFICER ID,**NEWID**,0)),H2)

Translate as:

> NEW MERGE ID COLUMN =  IF RESULT OF LEFT_JOIN(Transaction, MasterList,
> by = "OFFICER ID" = **"ID"**) **EQUAL NA** is TRUE THEN
>
> **OVERWRITE/REPLACE THE NA VALUE** WITH
> LEFT_JOIN(Transaction, MasterList, by = "OFFICER ID" = **"NEW ID"**)

my Working solution in R:

[enter image description here][1]

R Code:

```
id_list <- masterLIST_dataset %>% select("ID", "NEW ID")


MERGE_ID <- function({
  
 output1 <- Transaction_dataset %>%
            left_join(id_list, by = c("OFFICER ID" = "ID"), keep = TRUE) %>% 
            setnames("ID", "MERGE ID") 
 

 output2 <- output1 %>% 
            left_join(id_list, by = c("OFFICER ID" = "NEW ID")) %>%
            setnames("NEW ID", "MERGE ID") %>% select(-last_col())

 

 if (which(is.na(output1$"MERGE ID"), FALSE))
     output$"MERGE ID" <- output1$"MERGE ID"

 else if (which(is.na(output1$"MERGE ID"), TRUE))
     output$"MERGE ID" <- replace(which(is.na(output1$), TRUE), output2$"MERGE ID")
 
 output
             
  
})
```

**Sample Data & Desire Outcome is NEW_trans:**

```
> masterList <- data.frame("ID" = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), "NEW_ID" = c('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'))
> masterList
  ID NEW_ID
1  a     a1
2  b     b1
3  c     c1
4  d     d1
> 
> trans <- data.frame("OFFICER_ID" = c('a','a1', 'b', 'b1', 'c', 'c1', 'd'))
> trans
  OFFICER_ID
1          a
2         a1
3          b
4         b1
5          c
6         c1
7          d
> 
> NEW_trans <- data.frame("OFFICER_ID" = c('a','a1', 'b', 'b1', 'c', 'c1', 'd'), "MERGE_ID" = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'))
> NEW_trans
  OFFICER_ID MERGE_ID
1          a        a
2         a1        a
3          b        b
4         b1        b
5          c        c
6         c1        c
7          d        d
```

Comment: Apologize. Updated the code in post.

Comment: Update: Sample Data  & Desire Outcome to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the datasets and use `coalesce` to replace the `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)

trans %>%
  left_join(masterList, by = c('OFFICER_ID' = 'NEW_ID')) %>%
  mutate(ID = coalesce(ID, OFFICER_ID)) -> result

result
#  OFFICER_ID ID
#1          a  a
#2         a1  a
#3          b  b
#4         b1  b
#5          c  c
#6         c1  c
#7          d  d
```

Or in base R :

```
result <- transform(merge(trans, masterList, 
                    by.x = 'OFFICER_ID', by.y = 'NEW_ID', all.x = TRUE), 
                    ID = ifelse(is.na(ID), OFFICER_ID, ID))
```

Comment: Thank you ! Really Great - It solves the problem. Simple solution from both Base R and dplyr approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(trans)[masterList,  ID := fcoalesce(ID, 
        OFFICER_ID), on  = .(OFFICER_ID = NEW_ID)]
```